# Edit: Will Wasm/WASI implement processes with message passing?

Tags: module, webassembly, message-passing, wasi

Do the Wasm/WASI developers ever plan on implementing processes that can communicate with each other through message passing in the Wasm/WASI runtimes (without going through the JS runtime)?

### Old question:

Will the WebAssembly runtime be implementing message passing between modules, or are modules going to remain stateless? Or is that something WASI processes will have eventually?

Basically what I'm asking is: Will WebAssembly/WASI runtime ever have processes that can pass messages between each other? I'm guessing that's years away, but maybe it's not even on the agenda?

Comment: They are in the same JS main thread context. Why even message passing needed? They are just like other JS modules. Do JS modules ever need message passing?

Answer (score 0):

Wasm itself is addressing this largely via the Interface Types proposal. Learn more here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/08/webassembly-interface-types/